# Fluent interface for defining SQL commands and queries

Tags: java, fluent-interface

I created a set of classes for constructing SQL-Commands and Queries on various Database Management Systems.
All Classes support fluent programming and are working fine so far.

The main class is called SQL and has static methods INSERT() UPDATE() SELECT() ...
All of those methods return new instances of my classes SQLInsert(), SQLUpdate(), SQLSelect() ...

To make ist as short as possible I removed everything not neccessary for understanding how the classes work.

My class SQL

```
public class SQL {
    private SQL() {  }
    public static SQLInsert INSERT() { return new SQLInsert(); }
    public static SQLUpdate UPDATE() { return new SQLUpdate(); }
    // ...
}
```

My class SQLInsert

```
public class SQLInsert {
    // properties
    private String tableName;
    private final ArrayList<String> colNames = new ArrayList();
    // constructor
    public SQLInsert() { }
    // fluent methods
    public SQLInsert TABLE(String tbl) {
        tableName = tbl;
        return this;
    }
    public SQLInsert COLUMNS(String... cols) {
        for (String col : cols) { colNames.add(columnname); }
        return this;
    }
    // and so on
}
```

With this classes I can code like this:

```
SQL.INSERT().TABLE("test").COLUMNS("col1","col2").VALUES("test",100).execute(connection);
ResultSet rs = SQL.SELECT().COLUMNS("*").FROM("test").query(connection)
```

All of my classes only provide methods that make sense in context.
SQLInsert has no method WHERE() but a method SELECT() for defining sub-selects.

```
SQL.INSERT().TABLE("test").SELECT( 
    SQL.SELECT().COLUMNS(...).FROM(...) 
);
```

is a valid statement.

But now I need new classes for SQL-CREATE Statements. I would like to use my new class as follows

```
SQL.CREATE().TABLE(name). ...
SQL.CREATE().INDEX(name). ...
```

My class SQLCreate

```
public class SQLCreate {
    public SQLCreate() {}
    public static SQLCreateIndex INDEX(String name) {
        return new SQLCreateIndex(name);
    }
    public static SQLCreateTable TABLE(String name) {
        return new SQLCreateTable(name);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems not to work like expected.
After typing SQL.CREATE(). I have no access to the method INDEX()
Tested a lot, but nothing works. Can anyone give me the right hint?

Thx.

Comment: Where is the CREATE() method? Why are these INDEX() and TABLE() methods static? Why don't you respect the Java naming conventions?

Comment: You didn't actually paste that part but I assume that SQL class contains also
 public static SQLCreate CREATE() { return new SQLCreate(); } ?

Comment: remove the **static** modifier from `SQLCreate.SQLCreateIndex` and `SQLCreate.SQLCreateTable`.

Comment: @Pavel: you are right, I forgot to paste this line. Exactly like you said.

Comment: @JB: I didn't follow naming conventions because these methods represent SQL Keywords. Other not shown methods follow naming conventions, see execute().

Comment: @wero: Thanks al lot, this seems to work. Anyone interested in complete solution if it's ready?